# How to handle errors and "cancel" in Excel Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following script that prompts the user to save the file as an .xlsx with an initial filename "Report". If the user saves the document, everything saves correctly. But if the user selects "cancel" excel saves the file as "FALSE.xlsx". How can I make it not save the file at all and just leave it open?

```
path = "C:\Report\"
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=path & "Report", _
 fileFilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xlsx; *.xlsx),*.xlsx;*.xslx")
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Comment: enclose the saveas within an if statement to avoid that specific name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path = "C:\Report\"
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=path & "Report", _
                   fileFilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xls; *.xlsx),*.xls;*.xslx")
If fileSaveName <> False Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
End If
```

Comment: ...i had just closed this page after making the comment for this, then reopened the tab to post this.  Thanks, Tim!

Comment: @Cyril -  Sorry if I stepped on your answer

Comment: Didn't step over anything; you were all over it!  From the look of it, my comment wasn't as clear as my intent (which is what you put)

Comment: I appreciate both of your guys' help!